# i18n in jHipster entities

Tags: jhipster

I am creating a blog like application using jHipster and want to support i18n in 2 languages (English and Chinese). The jHipster page on this (https://jhipster.github.io/installing-new-languages/) explains i18n on UI elements only. 
But how to provide i18n support for values of entities? In this case I want Articles entity of blog to be in two languages. 
One of the workaround would be to get the values in both languages from the user into separate entity fields and display accordingly. Is it a right approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JHipster does not provide any helper for content localization. This must be done at JPA/Hibernate level.

You can have a field per language or an entity per language where `Article` would have a one-to-many relationship with `LocalizedArticle` that would contain all localized fields using a `Map<String, LocalizedArticle>` using locale as map key.

There are other options which are presented in this [good article](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/data-modeling-for-multiple-languages-how-to-design-a-localization-ready-system).